# IIS 7.5 Custom HTTP Response Headers Not Working

Tags: iis-7.5, http-headers

Trying to setup custom HTTP Response Headers on a new install of IIS7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and they are not working.  Default headers work fine (X-Powered-By, etc...).  Modifying default header values work (ie. change X-Powered-By to ASP.NET2).  Modifying default header names cause header to stop being output (ie. Change X-Powered-By to X-Powered-By2).

Site in question is a test site with a single html page.  Custom headers also don't work on ASP.NET 2.0 site.

I've tried setting the headers at the global level and at the site level to no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue ended up being our firewall stripping the response headers out.  Firewall had a list of approved headers and defaulted to stripping any not on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling [FREB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786638/how-can-i-get-gzip-compression-in-iis7-working/787251#787251). While it's not a 'failed request', FREB often gives me insight into what IIS is doing that I wouldn't have known otherwise.